# Arrange function in plyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

As I was doing the final assignment of coursera R programming course, my arrange function didnt actually worked well and I am fairly confused

as I have extract the state by split function

```
my_data<- outcome[,c(2,7,23)]
names(my_data)<- c("hospital","state","heart_attack","heart_failure","pneumonia")

my_data1<-lapply(split(my_data,my_data$state), data.frame)

my_data2<-arrange(my_data1$stateName, penumonia)
> arrange(my_data1$AK, pneumonia)

                                         hospital state     pneumonia
1                  PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER    AK          10.5
2  PEACEHEALTH KETCHIKAN MEDICAL             CENTER    AK          11.3
3                          SITKA COMMUNITY HOSPITAL    AK          11.5
4                        BARTLETT REGIONAL HOSPITAL    AK          11.6
5                    NORTON SOUND REGIONAL HOSPITAL    AK          11.6
6              PROVIDENCE KODIAK ISLAND MEDICAL CTR    AK          12.0
7                    MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    AK          12.1
8                          SOUTH PENINSULA HOSPITAL    AK          12.2
9                          ALASKA REGIONAL HOSPITAL    AK          12.5
10                      FAIRBANKS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AK          13.4
11               CENTRAL PENINSULA GENERAL HOSPITAL    AK          13.8
12                            MT EDGECUMBE HOSPITAL    AK          14.2
13                     ALASKA NATIVE MEDICAL CENTER    AK          15.5
14               YUKON KUSKOKWIM DELTA REG HOSPITAL    AK           9.7
```

which obviously

```
14               YUKON KUSKOKWIM DELTA REG HOSPITAL    AK           9.7
```

should be at the top.

Same result after I transform the column class to numeric.

So I have transformed the pneumonia column with

```
> class(my_data2$pneumonia)
[1] "character"
> my_data2$pneumonia <-as.numeric(my_data2$pneumonia)
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> class(my_data2$pneumonia)
[1] "numeric

> arrange(my_data2,pneumonia)
                                           hospital state pneumonia
1                YUKON KUSKOKWIM DELTA REG HOSPITAL    AK       9.7
2                  PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER    AK      10.5
3  PEACEHEALTH KETCHIKAN MEDICAL             CENTER    AK      11.3
4                          SITKA COMMUNITY HOSPITAL    AK      11.5
5                        BARTLETT REGIONAL HOSPITAL    AK      11.6
6                    NORTON SOUND REGIONAL HOSPITAL    AK      11.6
7              PROVIDENCE KODIAK ISLAND MEDICAL CTR    AK      12.0
8                    MAT-SU REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    AK      12.1
9                          SOUTH PENINSULA HOSPITAL    AK      12.2
10                         ALASKA REGIONAL HOSPITAL    AK      12.5
11                      FAIRBANKS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AK      13.4
12               CENTRAL PENINSULA GENERAL HOSPITAL    AK      13.8
13                            MT EDGECUMBE HOSPITAL    AK      14.2
14                     ALASKA NATIVE MEDICAL CENTER    AK      15.5
15                 PROVIDENCE VALDEZ MEDICAL CENTER    AK        NA
16                       PROVIDENCE SEWARD HOSPITAL    AK        NA
17                 CORDOVA COMMUNITY MEDICAL CENTER    AK        NA
```

and the problem solved, thanks for comment

Comment: What is the class of the `pneumonia` column? If it is `numeric`, you won't have problems...

Comment: Could you provide the output of `dput(outcome)`?